# How to restore wp_postmeta table in phpmyadmin mysql database - wordpress?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Unfortunately i have deleted wp_postmeta table from phpmyadmin mysql database.
After that my website doesn't show properly with contents.
So please help me to restore deleted table with info.

Comment: Unless you have a backup, you're out of luck.

Comment: Oh no...... There has no any option to retrieve the table in mysql?

Comment: No, deleted means deleted. You'll have to go with backups.